# How do I profile a Python script?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, time-complexity, profiling

[Project Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Euler) and other coding contests often have a maximum time to run or people boast of how fast their particular solution runs. With Python, sometimes the approaches are somewhat kludgey - i.e., adding timing code to `__main__`.

What is a good way to profile how long a Python program takes to run?

Comment: Project euler programs shouldn't need profiling.  Either you have an algorithm that works in under a minute, or you have entirely the wrong algorithm.  "Tuning" is rarely appropriate.  You generally have to take a fresh approach.

Comment: S.Lott: Profiling is often a helpful way to determine which subroutines are slow.  Subroutines that take a long time are great candidates for algorithmic improvement.

Comment: It's worth mentioning two packages: [py-spy](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy) and [nvtx](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-tools-extension-api-nvtx-annotation-tool-for-profiling-code-in-python-and-c-c/) for cases when the code runs on CPUs and/or GPUs.

Comment: There's also `line-profiler`, for line-by-line profiling

Answer (score 1750, accepted):

**Python includes a profiler called [`cProfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile).** It not only gives the total running time, but also times each function separately, and tells you how many times each function was called, making it easy to determine where you should make optimizations.

You can call it from within your code, or from the interpreter, like this:

```
import cProfile
cProfile.run('foo()')
```

Even more usefully, you can invoke cProfile when running a script:

```
python -m cProfile myscript.py
```

Or when running a module:

```
python -m cProfile -m mymodule
```

To make it even easier, I made a little batch file called 'profile.bat':

```
python -m cProfile %1
```

So all I have to do is run:

```
profile euler048.py
```

And I get this:

```
1007 function calls in 0.061 CPU seconds

Ordered by: standard name
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.061    0.061 <string>:1(<module>)
 1000    0.051    0.000    0.051    0.000 euler048.py:2(<lambda>)
    1    0.005    0.005    0.061    0.061 euler048.py:2(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.061    0.061 {execfile}
    1    0.002    0.002    0.053    0.053 {map}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
    1    0.003    0.003    0.003    0.003 {sum}
```

EDIT: Updated link to a good video resource from PyCon 2013 titled
[***Python Profiling***](https://web.archive.org/web/20170318204046/http://lanyrd.com/2013/pycon/scdywg/)
[Also via YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJwVYlDzAXs).

Comment: Also it is useful to sort the results, that can be done by -s switch, example: '-s time'. You can use cumulative/name/time/file sorting options.

Comment: Unfortunately, though, you can't sort percall for either the total or cumulative times, which is a major deficiency IMO.

Comment: Also read the python documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) it's pretty good

Comment: It is also worth noting that you can use the cProfile module from ipython using the magic function %prun (profile run). First import your module, and then call the main function with %prun: import euler048; %prun euler048.main()

Comment: For visualizing cProfile dumps (created by `python -m cProfile -o <out.profile> <script>`), [RunSnakeRun](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/), invoked as `runsnake <out.profile>` is invaluable.

Comment: This answer should probably be updated for python 3: just use `profile`.

Comment: If my code doesn't terminate then is there any way to give cut off time to your profiler?

Comment: @NeilG even for python 3, [**`cprofile` is still recommended**](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/profile.html) over `profile`.

Comment: to add to the answer  if you need to run it from the code and generate an output file, you could use  import cProfile
cProfile.run('foo()', 'somefilename')

Comment: for example, the profile prints {map} or {xxx} . how do I know the method {xxx} is called from which file? my profile prints {method 'compress' of 'zlib.Compress' objects} takes most of time, but I don't use any zlib , so I guess some call numpy function may use it . How do I know which is the exactly file and line takes much time?

Comment: For visualizing cProfile dumps, RunSnakeRun hasn't been updated since 2011 and doesn't support python3. You should use [snakeviz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/) instead

Comment: Another downside to cProfile is that it's impossible to do anything _other_ than print the output to the console. If you want to capture the timings/store them in a metrics system/for reporting later, you're going to be manually parsing lines of console output.

Comment: I usually find cumtime is what you actually care about (this is what is worth optimizing) for ease of use:

`python -m cProfile -s cumtime pyname.py`

Comment: If you want to run a module instead of a script, just use the `-m` flag again.  Example: `python -m cProfile -m myModule`

Comment: @cowlinator, What's the difference; aren't all scripts importable as modules? Or will cProfile profile the function definitions as well?

Comment: All scripts are importable as modules, but not all modules are runnable as scripts.  If `python mymodule.py` fails because it requires `python -m mymodule`, then `python -m cProfile mymodule.py` will also fail.  So use `python -m cProfile -m mymodule`.

Comment: To visualize the results of `cProfile`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37157132/2491528

Comment: One-liner to sort and limit to 20 lines printed `import cProfile, pstats; pstats.Stats(cProfile.Profile().run("foo()")).sort_stats(pstats.SortKey.CUMULATIVE).print_stats(20)`

Answer (score 521):

A while ago I made [`pycallgraph`](https://pycallgraph.readthedocs.io/en/master/) which generates a visualisation from your Python code. **Edit:** I've updated the example to work with 3.3, the latest release as of this writing.

After a `pip install pycallgraph` and installing [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) you can run it from the command line:

```
pycallgraph graphviz -- ./mypythonscript.py
```

Or, you can profile particular parts of your code:

```
from pycallgraph import PyCallGraph
from pycallgraph.output import GraphvizOutput

with PyCallGraph(output=GraphvizOutput()):
    code_to_profile()
```

Either of these will generate a `pycallgraph.png` file similar to the image below:

[image]

Comment: Are you coloring based on the amount of calls? If so, you should color based on time because the function with the most calls isn't always the one that takes the most time.

Comment: @red You can customise colours however you like, and even independently for each measurement. For example red for calls, blue for time, green for memory usage.

Comment: @Gerald, this doesn't work. Yes Pip install, well installs, but it says it can't find graphviz when I run the command. I even did `apt-get install graphviz`, no difference. running the terminal with 'graphviz' shows command not found. What am I doing wrong? I'm using Linux Mint 15.

Comment: @Matt Please post your bug report on [pycallgraph issue tracker](https://github.com/gak/pycallgraph/issues). Stackoverflow isn't the place for pycallgraph support :) I'll download Mint to test it out for you in the mean time.

Comment: @Matt if you install mint over an Ubuntu grub, something messes up your /etc/sources.list.  Consider LMDE.

Comment: getting this error`Traceback (most recent call last):
/pycallgraph.py", line 90, in generate
    output.done()
  File "/net_downloaded/pycallgraph-develop/pycallgraph/output/graphviz.py", line 94, in done
    source = self.generate()
  File "/net_downloaded/pycallgraph-develop/pycallgraph/output/graphviz.py", line 143, in generate
    indent_join.join(self.generate_attributes()),
  File "/net_downloaded/pycallgraph-develop/pycallgraph/output/graphviz.py", line 169, in generate_attributes
    section, self.attrs_from_dict(attrs),
ValueError: zero length field name in format`

Comment: For some reason it works for me if I use it like "pycallgraph -- ./mypythonscript.py" the argument graphviz seems redundant.

Comment: I updated this to mention that you need to install GraphViz for things to work as described. On Ubuntu this is just `sudo apt-get install graphviz`.

Comment: This requires a bit of work to install here is 3 steps to help. 1. Install via pip, 2. Install GraphViz via exe 3. Set up path variables to GraphViz directory 4. Figure out how to fix all the other errors. 5. Figure out where it saves the png file?

Comment: I've found call graphs to be useful only with a limited number of nodes; real programs that I use tend to fill up a huge area and make the resulting drawing incomprehensible. I'd rather use [flame graphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html).

Comment: The [github page](https://github.com/gak/pycallgraph)  states that this project is  abandoned ... :(

Comment: Does anyone know how we can set the colors to change based on memory usage? Unfortunately the documentation is very perfunctory and short!

Comment: Was getting this error "/usr/bin/python3: No module named pycallgraph.__main__; 'pycallgraph' is a package and cannot be directly executed" so I sudo apt install python3-pycallgraph graphviz

Comment: pycallgraph has been abandoned. I couldn't get it to install from pip on a modern python version. But I just tried pycallgraph2 and it works great: https://github.com/daneads/pycallgraph2

Answer (score 237):

It's worth pointing out that using the profiler only works (by default) on the main thread, and you won't get any information from other threads if you use them.  This can be a bit of a gotcha as it is completely unmentioned in the [profiler documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html).

If you also want to profile threads, you'll want to look at the [`threading.setprofile()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.setprofile) in the docs.

You could also create your own `threading.Thread` subclass to do it:

```
class ProfiledThread(threading.Thread):
    # Overrides threading.Thread.run()
    def run(self):
        profiler = cProfile.Profile()
        try:
            return profiler.runcall(threading.Thread.run, self)
        finally:
            profiler.dump_stats('myprofile-%d.profile' % (self.ident,))
```

and use that `ProfiledThread` class instead of the standard one.  It might give you more flexibility, but I'm not sure it's worth it, especially if you are using third-party code which wouldn't use your class.

Comment: I don't see any reference to runcall in the documentation either. Giving a look at cProfile.py, I'm not sure why you use the threading.Thread.run function nor self as argument. I'd have expected to see a reference to _another_ thread's run method here.

Comment: It's not in the documentation, but it is in the module.  See http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6bf07db23445/Lib/cProfile.py#l140.  That allows you to profile a specific function call, and in our case we want to profile the Thread's `target` function, which is what the `threading.Thread.run()` call executes.  But as I said in the answer, it's probably not worth it to subclass Thread, since any third-party code won't use it, and to instead use `threading.setprofile()`.

Comment: wrapping the code with profiler.enable() and profiler.disable() seems to work quite well, too. That's basically what runcall do and it doesn't enforce any number of argument or similar things.

Comment: I combined my own http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748118/starting-debugger-on-errors-in-threads with http://ddaa.net/blog/python/lsprof-calltree and it kindof works ;!-)

Comment: Joe, do you know how the profiler plays with asyncio in Python 3.4?

Comment: @NickChammas I have no idea, I'm sorry.  I speculate that the guts of the asyncio code are written in C, so the profiler wouldn't be able to touch them.

Comment: Maybe important to note that such an approach doesn't work for parallelizing using multiprocessing (effectively multicore, overcoming the global interpreter lock). Despite that multiprocessing reproduces most of the APIs of the threading module, it's explicitly mentioned in the doc that `threading.setprofile()` has none. Quoting the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html): "`multiprocessing` contains no analogues of [...] `threading.setprofile()`"

Answer (score 180):

The python wiki is a great page for profiling resources:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Profiling_Code

as is the python docs:
http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html

as shown by Chris Lawlor cProfile is a great tool and can easily be used to print to the screen:

```
python -m cProfile -s time mine.py <args>
```

or to file:

```
python -m cProfile -o output.file mine.py <args>
```

PS> If you are using Ubuntu, make sure to install python-profile

```
apt-get install python-profiler
```

If you output to file you can get nice visualizations using the following tools

PyCallGraph : a tool to create call graph images 
  install:

```
 pip install pycallgraph
```

run:

```
 pycallgraph mine.py args
```

view:

```
 gimp pycallgraph.png
```

*You can use whatever you like to view the png file, I used gimp*
Unfortunately I often get

dot: graph is too large for cairo-renderer bitmaps. Scaling by 0.257079 to fit

which makes my images unusably small.  So I generally create svg files:

```
pycallgraph -f svg -o pycallgraph.svg mine.py <args>
```

PS> make sure to install graphviz (which provides the dot program):

```
pip install graphviz
```

Alternative Graphing using gprof2dot via @maxy / @quodlibetor :

```
pip install gprof2dot
python -m cProfile -o profile.pstats mine.py
gprof2dot -f pstats profile.pstats | dot -Tsvg -o mine.svg
```

Comment: [gprof2dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot) can do those graphs too. I think the output is a bit nicer ([example](http://maxy.homeip.net/misc/profile_tiny_straight_line_preview.png)).

Comment: graphviz is also required if you are using OSX

Comment: Project was archived on github and appears to be no longer maintained. https://github.com/gak/pycallgraph

Answer (score 177):

**Simplest** and **quickest** way to find where all the time is going.

```
1. pip install snakeviz

2. python -m cProfile -o temp.dat <PROGRAM>.py

3. snakeviz temp.dat
```

Draws a pie chart in a browser. Biggest piece is the problem function. Very simple.

Comment: See also [zaxliu’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37431235/711006) which provides a link to the tool and example output.

Comment: Using this on windows, created a bat script for pycharm integration, it works like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 168):

@Maxy's comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7693928/25616) helped me out enough that I think it deserves its own answer: I already had cProfile-generated .pstats files and I didn't want to re-run things with pycallgraph, so I used [gprof2dot](https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot), and got pretty svgs:

```
$ sudo apt-get install graphviz
$ git clone https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot
$ ln -s "$PWD"/gprof2dot/gprof2dot.py ~/bin
$ cd $PROJECT_DIR
$ gprof2dot.py -f pstats profile.pstats | dot -Tsvg -o callgraph.svg
```

and BLAM!

It uses dot (the same thing that pycallgraph uses) so output looks similar. I get the impression that gprof2dot loses less information though:

[image: gprof2dot example output]

Comment: Good approach, works really well as you can view SVG in Chrome etc and scale it up/down.  Third line has typo, should be: ln -s ``pwd``/gprof2dot/gprof2dot.py $HOME/bin  (or use ln -s $PWD/gprof2dot/gprof2dot.py ~/bin in most shells - grave accent is taken as formatting in first version).

Comment: Ah, good point. I get `ln`'s argument-order wrong almost every time.

Comment: the trick is to remember that ln and cp have the same argument order - think of it as 'copying file1 to file2 or dir2, but making a link'

Comment: That makes sense, I think the use of "TARGET" in the manpage throws me.

Comment: Please, how did you get rounded corners? I feel it improves readability. I just get ugly sharp corners which is not cool in the presence of many edges around boxes.

Comment: Sorry @Hibou57 that is just the default output for me. Maybe try upgrading or downgrading `dot`?

Comment: Great solution! At first I thought that the tool was useless as it only showed 5 calls but to show everything add -n0 -e0 to the arguments.

Comment: Thanks @quodlibetor! On Win 10, depending on the conda or pip install, the command line editor might claim that `dot` is not recognizable. Setting a PATH for dot is not advisable e.g. as per https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1666. One can use the full path of graphviz dot instead, e.g.: i) `python -m cProfile -o profile.pstats main.py
` ii) `gprof2dot -f pstats profile.pstats | "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe" -Tsvg -o gprof2dot_pstats.svg`.

Answer (score 111):

I ran into a handy tool called [SnakeViz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/) when researching this topic. SnakeViz is a web-based profiling visualization tool. It is very easy to install and use. The usual way I use it is to generate a stat file with `%prun` and then do analysis in SnakeViz.

The main viz technique used is **Sunburst chart** as shown below, in which the hierarchy of function calls is arranged as layers of arcs and time info encoded in their angular widths.

The best thing is you can interact with the chart. For example, to zoom in one can click on an arc, and the arc and its descendants will be enlarged as a new sunburst to display more details.

[image]

Comment: [CodeCabbie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49173782/5728089) includes the (short) installation instructions, and shows how to (easily) use SnakeViz.

Comment: Here I've read IMHO good guide how to use profiling for Python on jupyter notebook: https://towardsdatascience.com/speed-up-jupyter-notebooks-20716cbe2025

Answer (score 104):

[`cProfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) is great for profiling, while [`kcachegrind`](https://kcachegrind.github.io/html/Home.html) is great for visualizing the results. The [`pyprof2calltree`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyprof2calltree) in between handles the file conversion.

```
python -m cProfile -o script.profile script.py
pyprof2calltree -i script.profile -o script.calltree
kcachegrind script.calltree
```

Required system packages:

- `kcachegrind` (Linux), `qcachegrind` (MacOs)

Setup on Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install kcachegrind 
pip install pyprof2calltree
```

The result:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Comment: Mac Users install ```brew install qcachegrind``` and substitude each ```kcachegrind```  with ```qcachegrind ``` in the description for successful profiling.

Comment: I had to do this to get it to work: `export QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1`

Comment: Out of bunch of solutions listed here: this one worked best with large profile data. 
`gprof2dot` is not interactive and does not have the overall cpu time (only relative percentage)
`tuna` and `snakeviz`  die on larger profile. 
`pycallgraph` is archived and no longer maintained

Comment: @YonatanSimson You probably run `kcachegrind` in a docker container, which doesn't share IPC with the host by default. Another way to fix that is to run the docker container with `--ipc=host`.

Answer (score 68):

I recently created [tuna](https://github.com/nschloe/tuna) for visualizing Python runtime and import profiles; this may be helpful here.

[image]

Install with

```
pip install tuna
```

Create a runtime profile

```
python3 -m cProfile -o program.prof yourfile.py
```

or an import profile (Python 3.7+ required)

```
python3 -X importprofile yourfile.py 2> import.log
```

Then just run tuna on the file

```
tuna program.prof
```

Comment: This was the first solution that worked well for me.

Comment: Kudos and thanks for creating `Tuna`. Among the solutions shown on this page, yours and `pyinstrument` were the best in figuring out what was taking up the most time in my app.

Answer (score 43):

Also worth mentioning is the GUI cProfile dump viewer [RunSnakeRun](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/).  It allows you to sort and select, thereby zooming in on the relevant parts of the program.  The sizes of the rectangles in the picture is proportional to the time taken.  If you mouse over a rectangle it highlights that call in the table and everywhere on the map.  When you double-click on a rectangle it zooms in on that portion.  It will show you who calls that portion and what that portion calls.

The descriptive information is very helpful.  It shows you the code for that bit which can be helpful when you are dealing with built-in library calls.  It tells you what file and what line to find the code.

Also want to point at that the OP said 'profiling' but it appears he meant 'timing'.  Keep in mind programs will run slower when profiled.

[image]

Comment: This screenshot is evidence that Engineers need to be taught at least one chapter on how to use colors in GUI's. I've worked with Interaction Designers who'd turn away in disgust, on seeing this splosh of random colors.

Answer (score 40):

## pprofile

`line_profiler` (already presented here) also inspired  [`pprofile`](https://github.com/vpelletier/pprofile), which is described as:

> Line-granularity, thread-aware deterministic and statistic pure-python
>   profiler

It provides line-granularity as `line_profiler`, is pure Python, can be used as a standalone command or a module, and can even generate callgrind-format files that can be easily analyzed with `[k|q]cachegrind`.

## vprof

There is also [vprof](https://github.com/nvdv/vprof), a Python package described as:

> [...] providing rich and interactive visualizations for various Python program characteristics such as running time and memory usage.

[image: heatmap]

Comment: Haven't tried `pprofile`, but I'm upvoting `vprof`. Its "code heatmap" mode is similar to the Matlab profiler. Currently, correct usage on Windows is not in the readme, but in `vprof`'s GitHub issues: `py -m vprof -c <config> <src>`

Answer (score 38):

A nice profiling module is the line_profiler (called using the script kernprof.py).  It can be downloaded [here](http://packages.python.org/line_profiler/).

My understanding is that cProfile only gives information about total time spent in each function.  So individual lines of code are not timed.  This is an issue in scientific computing since often one single line can take a lot of time.  Also, as I remember, cProfile didn't catch the time I was spending in say numpy.dot.

Comment: Note that the original repository has been archived. 
The currently maintained version is here: https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler

Answer (score 35):

The terminal-only (and simplest) solution, in case all those fancy UI's fail to install or to run:
ignore `cProfile` completely and replace it with `pyinstrument`, that will collect and display the tree of calls right after execution.

Install:

```
$ pip install pyinstrument
```

Profile and display result:

```
$ python -m pyinstrument ./prog.py
```

Works with python2 and 3.

[EDIT]
The documentation of the API, for profiling only a part of the code, can be found [here](https://github.com/joerick/pyinstrument#profile-a-specific-chunk-of-code).

Comment: Thank you, I think your answer should be much higher :)

Comment: This is exactly the thing I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

With a statistical profiler like [austin](https://github.com/P403n1x87/austin), no instrumentation is required, meaning that you can get profiling data out of a Python application simply with

```
austin python3 my_script.py
```

The raw output isn't very useful, but you can pipe that to [flamegraph.pl](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph/blob/master/flamegraph.pl)
to get a flame graph representation of that data that gives you a breakdown of where the time (measured in microseconds of real time) is being spent.

```
austin python3 my_script.py | flamegraph.pl > my_script_profile.svg
```

Alternatively, you can also use the web application [Speedscope.app](http://speedscope.app/) for quick visualisation of the collected samples. If you have [pprof](https://github.com/google/pprof) installed, you can also get [austin-python](https://github.com/P403n1x87/austin-python) (with e.g. `pipx install austin-python`) and use the `austin2pprof` to covert to the pprof format.

However, if you have VS Code installed you could use the [Austin extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=p403n1x87.austin-vscode) for a more interactive experience, with source code heat maps, top functions and collected call stacks

[image: Austin VS Code extension]

If you'd rather use the terminal, you can also use the [TUI](https://github.com/p403n1x87/austin-tui), that also has a live graph mode:

[image: Austin TUI graph mode]

Answer (score 22):

There's a lot of great answers but they either use command line or some external program for profiling and/or sorting the results.

I really missed some way I could use in my IDE (eclipse-PyDev) without touching the command line or installing anything. So here it is.

## Profiling without command line

```
def count():
    from math import sqrt
    for x in range(10**5):
        sqrt(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import cProfile, pstats
    cProfile.run("count()", "{}.profile".format(__file__))
    s = pstats.Stats("{}.profile".format(__file__))
    s.strip_dirs()
    s.sort_stats("time").print_stats(10)
```

See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/profile.html) or other answers for more info.

Comment: for example, the profile prints {map} or {xxx} . how do I know the method {xxx} is called from which file? my profile prints {method 'compress' of 'zlib.Compress' objects} takes most of time, but I don't use any zlib , so I guess some call numpy function may use it . How do I know which is the exactly file and line takes much time?

Comment: This isn't fair... I dunno why this great answer has so few upvotes... much more useful than the other high-upvoted ones :/

Answer (score 14):

Following Joe Shaw's answer about multi-threaded code not to work as expected, I figured that the `runcall` method in cProfile is merely doing `self.enable()` and `self.disable()` calls around the profiled function call, so you can simply do that yourself and have whatever code you want in-between with minimal interference with existing code.

Comment: Excellent tip! A quick peek at `cprofile.py`'s source code reveals that's _exactly_ what `runcall()` does. Being more specific, after creating a Profile instance with `prof = cprofile.Profile()`, immediately call `prof.disable()`, and then just add `prof.enable()` and `prof.disable()` calls around the section of code you want profiled.

Comment: This is very helpful, but it seems **the code that is actually between enable and disable is not profiled** -- only the functions it calls. Do I have this right?  I'd have to wrap that code in a function call for it to count toward any of the numbers in print_stats().

Answer (score 13):

For getting quick profile stats on an IPython notebook.
One can embed **line_profiler** and **memory_profiler** straight into their notebooks.

Another useful package is **Pympler**. It is a powerful profiling package that's capable to track classes,objects,functions,memory leaks etc. Examples below, Docs attached.

### Get it!

```py
!pip install line_profiler
!pip install memory_profiler
!pip install pympler
```

### Load it!

```py
%load_ext line_profiler
%load_ext memory_profiler
```

### Use it!

---

## %time

```py
%time print('Outputs CPU time,Wall Clock time') 
#CPU times: user 2 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 2 µs Wall time: 5.96 µs
```

Gives:

- CPU times: CPU level execution time
- sys times: system level execution time
- total: CPU time + system time
- Wall time: Wall Clock Time

---

## %timeit

```py
%timeit -r 7 -n 1000 print('Outputs execution time of the snippet') 
#1000 loops, best of 7: 7.46 ns per loop
```

- Gives best time out of given number of runs(r) in looping (n) times.
- Outputs details on system caching:

  - When code snippets are executed multiple times, system caches a few opearations and doesn't execute them again that may hamper the accuracy of the profile reports.

---

## %prun

```py
%prun -s cumulative 'Code to profile'
```

Gives:

- number of function calls(ncalls)
- has entries per function call(distinct)
- time taken per call(percall)
- time elapsed till that function call(cumtime)
- name of the func/module called etc...

[image: Cumulative profile]

---

## %memit

```py
%memit 'Code to profile'
#peak memory: 199.45 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB
```

Gives:

- Memory usage

---

## %lprun

```py
#Example function
def fun():
  for i in range(10):
    print(i)

#Usage: %lprun <name_of_the_function> function
%lprun -f fun fun()
```

Gives:

- Line wise stats

[image: LineProfile]

---

## sys.getsizeof

```py
sys.getsizeof('code to profile')
# 64 bytes
```

Returns the size of an object in bytes.

---

## asizeof() from pympler

```py
from pympler import asizeof
obj = [1,2,("hey","ha"),3]
print(asizeof.asizeof(obj,stats=4))
```

pympler.asizeof can be used to investigate how much memory certain Python objects consume.
In contrast to sys.getsizeof, asizeof sizes objects recursively

[image: pympler.asizeof]

---

## tracker from pympler

```py
from pympler import tracker
tr = tracker.SummaryTracker()
def fun():
  li = [1,2,3]
  di = {"ha":"haha","duh":"Umm"}
fun()
tr.print_diff()
```

Tracks the lifetime of a function.

[image: tracker output]

Pympler package consists of a huge number of high utility functions to profile code. All of which cannot be covered here. See the documentation attached for verbose profile implementations.

#### Pympler [doc](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pympler/downloads/pdf/latest/)

Answer (score 11):

In Virtaal's [source](https://github.com/translate/virtaal/blob/master/devsupport/profiling.py) there's a very useful class and decorator that can make profiling (even for specific methods/functions) very easy. The output can then be viewed very comfortably in KCacheGrind.

Comment: Thank you for this gem. FYI: This can be used as a standalone module with any code, Virtaal code base is not required. Just save the file to profiling.py and import the profile_func(). Use @profile_func() as a decorator to any function you need to profile and viola. :)

Answer (score 11):

Recently I created a plugin for PyCharm with which you can easily analyse and visualise the results of `line_profiler` in the PyCharm editor.

`line_profiler` has been mentioned in other answers as well and is a great tool to analyse exactly how much time is spent by the python interpreter in certain lines.

The PyCharm plugin I've created can be found here:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16536-line-profiler

It needs a helper package in your python environment called `line-profiler-pycharm` which can be installed with pip or by the plugin itself.

After installing the plugin in PyCharm:

1. Decorate any function you want to profile with the `line_profiler_pycharm.profile` decorator
2. Run with the 'Profile Lines' runner

Screenshot of results:
[image: Line Profiler Pycharm results]

Comment: Pretty neat, easily implemented!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to make a cumulative profiler,
meaning to run the function several times in a row and watch the sum of the results.

you can use this `cumulative_profiler` decorator:

it's python >= 3.6 specific, but you can remove `nonlocal` for it work on older versions.

```
import cProfile, pstats

class _ProfileFunc:
    def __init__(self, func, sort_stats_by):
        self.func =  func
        self.profile_runs = []
        self.sort_stats_by = sort_stats_by

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pr = cProfile.Profile()
        pr.enable()  # this is the profiling section
        retval = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        pr.disable()

        self.profile_runs.append(pr)
        ps = pstats.Stats(*self.profile_runs).sort_stats(self.sort_stats_by)
        return retval, ps

def cumulative_profiler(amount_of_times, sort_stats_by='time'):
    def real_decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal function, amount_of_times, sort_stats_by  # for python 2.x remove this row

            profiled_func = _ProfileFunc(function, sort_stats_by)
            for i in range(amount_of_times):
                retval, ps = profiled_func(*args, **kwargs)
            ps.print_stats()
            return retval  # returns the results of the function
        return wrapper

    if callable(amount_of_times):  # incase you don't want to specify the amount of times
        func = amount_of_times  # amount_of_times is the function in here
        amount_of_times = 5  # the default amount
        return real_decorator(func)
    return real_decorator
```

**Example**

profiling the function `baz`

```
import time

@cumulative_profiler
def baz():
    time.sleep(1)
    time.sleep(2)
    return 1

baz()
```

`baz` ran 5 times and printed this:

```
         20 function calls in 15.003 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       10   15.003    1.500   15.003    1.500 {built-in method time.sleep}
        5    0.000    0.000   15.003    3.001 <ipython-input-9-c89afe010372>:3(baz)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

specifying the amount of times

```
@cumulative_profiler(3)
def baz():
    ...
```

Answer (score 9):

I just developed my own profiler inspired from pypref_time:

https://github.com/modaresimr/auto_profiler

## Update Version 2

### Install:

```
pip install auto_profiler
```

### Quick Start:

```
from auto_profiler import Profiler

with Profiler():
    your_function()
```

### Using in Jupyter, let you have realtime view of elapsed times

[image: Real Time view of auto profiler in jupyter]

## Update Version 1

By adding a decorator it will show a tree of time-consuming functions

`@Profiler(depth=4)`

```
Install by: pip install auto_profiler
```

## Example

```py
import time # line number 1
import random

from auto_profiler import Profiler, Tree

def f1():
    mysleep(.6+random.random())

def mysleep(t):
    time.sleep(t)

def fact(i):
    f1()
    if(i==1):
        return 1
    return i*fact(i-1)

def main():
    for i in range(5):
        f1()

    fact(3)


with Profiler(depth=4):
    main()
```

### Example Output

```
Time   [Hits * PerHit] Function name [Called from] [function location]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
8.974s [1 * 8.974]  main  [auto-profiler/profiler.py:267]  [/test/t2.py:30]
├── 5.954s [5 * 1.191]  f1  [/test/t2.py:34]  [/test/t2.py:14]
│   └── 5.954s [5 * 1.191]  mysleep  [/test/t2.py:15]  [/test/t2.py:17]
│       └── 5.954s [5 * 1.191]  <time.sleep>
|
|
|   # The rest is for the example recursive function call fact
└── 3.020s [1 * 3.020]  fact  [/test/t2.py:36]  [/test/t2.py:20]
    ├── 0.849s [1 * 0.849]  f1  [/test/t2.py:21]  [/test/t2.py:14]
    │   └── 0.849s [1 * 0.849]  mysleep  [/test/t2.py:15]  [/test/t2.py:17]
    │       └── 0.849s [1 * 0.849]  <time.sleep>
    └── 2.171s [1 * 2.171]  fact  [/test/t2.py:24]  [/test/t2.py:20]
        ├── 1.552s [1 * 1.552]  f1  [/test/t2.py:21]  [/test/t2.py:14]
        │   └── 1.552s [1 * 1.552]  mysleep  [/test/t2.py:15]  [/test/t2.py:17]
        └── 0.619s [1 * 0.619]  fact  [/test/t2.py:24]  [/test/t2.py:20]
            └── 0.619s [1 * 0.619]  f1  [/test/t2.py:21]  [/test/t2.py:14]
```

Comment: Wow, for such a cool profiler, why not more stars on GitHub?

Comment: @Dan Nissenbaum, I'm so happy to hear your interest. I don't have a big network so no one knows this tool. I hope I can continue maintaining this project by hearing such interests

Answer (score 8):

cProfile is great for quick profiling but most of the time it was ending for me with the errors. Function runctx solves this problem by initializing correctly the environment and variables, hope it can be useful for someone:

```
import cProfile
cProfile.runctx('foo()', None, locals())
```

Answer (score 8):

**gprof2dot_magic**

Magic function for `gprof2dot` to profile any Python statement as a DOT graph in JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook.

[image]

GitHub repo: https://github.com/mattijn/gprof2dot_magic

**installation**

Make sure you've the Python package `gprof2dot_magic`.

```
pip install gprof2dot_magic
```

Its dependencies `gprof2dot` and `graphviz` will be installed as well

**usage**

To enable the magic function, first load the `gprof2dot_magic` module

```
%load_ext gprof2dot_magic
```

and then profile any line statement as a DOT graph as such:

```
%gprof2dot print('hello world')
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

My way is to use yappi (https://github.com/sumerc/yappi). It's especially useful combined with an RPC server where (even just for debugging) you register method to start, stop and print profiling information, e.g. in this way:

```
@staticmethod
def startProfiler():
    yappi.start()

@staticmethod
def stopProfiler():
    yappi.stop()

@staticmethod
def printProfiler():
    stats = yappi.get_stats(yappi.SORTTYPE_TTOT, yappi.SORTORDER_DESC, 20)
    statPrint = '\n'
    namesArr = [len(str(stat[0])) for stat in stats.func_stats]
    log.debug("namesArr %s", str(namesArr))
    maxNameLen = max(namesArr)
    log.debug("maxNameLen: %s", maxNameLen)

    for stat in stats.func_stats:
        nameAppendSpaces = [' ' for i in range(maxNameLen - len(stat[0]))]
        log.debug('nameAppendSpaces: %s', nameAppendSpaces)
        blankSpace = ''
        for space in nameAppendSpaces:
            blankSpace += space

        log.debug("adding spaces: %s", len(nameAppendSpaces))
        statPrint = statPrint + str(stat[0]) + blankSpace + " " + str(stat[1]).ljust(8) + "\t" + str(
            round(stat[2], 2)).ljust(8 - len(str(stat[2]))) + "\t" + str(round(stat[3], 2)) + "\n"

    log.log(1000, "\nname" + ''.ljust(maxNameLen - 4) + " ncall \tttot \ttsub")
    log.log(1000, statPrint)
```

Then when your program work you can start profiler at any time by calling the `startProfiler` RPC method and dump profiling information to a log file by calling `printProfiler` (or modify the rpc method to return it to the caller) and get such output:

```
2014-02-19 16:32:24,128-|SVR-MAIN  |-(Thread-3   )-Level 1000: 
name                                                                                                                                      ncall     ttot    tsub
2014-02-19 16:32:24,128-|SVR-MAIN  |-(Thread-3   )-Level 1000: 
C:\Python27\lib\sched.py.run:80                                                                                                           22        0.11    0.05
M:\02_documents\_repos\09_aheadRepos\apps\ahdModbusSrv\pyAheadRpcSrv\xmlRpc.py.iterFnc:293                                                22        0.11    0.0
M:\02_documents\_repos\09_aheadRepos\apps\ahdModbusSrv\serverMain.py.makeIteration:515                                                    22        0.11    0.0
M:\02_documents\_repos\09_aheadRepos\apps\ahdModbusSrv\pyAheadRpcSrv\PicklingXMLRPC.py._dispatch:66                                       1         0.0     0.0
C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py.date_time_string:464                                                                                    1         0.0     0.0
c:\users\zasiec~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-hwcsr1\psutil-1.1.2-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\psutil\_psmswindows.py._get_raw_meminfo:243     4         0.0     0.0
C:\Python27\lib\SimpleXMLRPCServer.py.decode_request_content:537                                                                          1         0.0     0.0
c:\users\zasiec~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-hwcsr1\psutil-1.1.2-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\psutil\_psmswindows.py.get_system_cpu_times:148 4         0.0     0.0
<string>.__new__:8                                                                                                                        220       0.0     0.0
C:\Python27\lib\socket.py.close:276                                                                                                       4         0.0     0.0
C:\Python27\lib\threading.py.__init__:558                                                                                                 1         0.0     0.0
<string>.__new__:8                                                                                                                        4         0.0     0.0
C:\Python27\lib\threading.py.notify:372                                                                                                   1         0.0     0.0
C:\Python27\lib\rfc822.py.getheader:285                                                                                                   4         0.0     0.0
C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py.handle_one_request:301                                                                                  1         0.0     0.0
C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py.end:816                                                                                                      3         0.0     0.0
C:\Python27\lib\SimpleXMLRPCServer.py.do_POST:467                                                                                         1         0.0     0.0
C:\Python27\lib\SimpleXMLRPCServer.py.is_rpc_path_valid:460                                                                               1         0.0     0.0
C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py.close_request:475                                                                                         1         0.0     0.0
c:\users\zasiec~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-hwcsr1\psutil-1.1.2-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\psutil\__init__.py.cpu_times:1066               4         0.0     0.0
```

It may not be very useful for short scripts but helps to optimize server-type processes especially given the `printProfiler` method can be called multiple times over time to profile and compare e.g. different program usage scenarios.

In newer versions of yappi, the following code will work:

```
@staticmethod
def printProfile():
    yappi.get_func_stats().print_all()
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be named the Stupendous Yappi?

Comment: Unfortunately the code above works only with version 0.62 which is not available on pypy. Module needs to be compiled from 0.62 sources available here: https://github.com/nirs/yappi/releases or use build I made for windows in repo forked for that purpose https://github.com/Girgitt/yappi/releases

Comment: compatibility with version 1.0 can be easily provided - at least for print output - by modifying the printProfiler function:

```def printProfiler():
    if not yappi_available:
        return

    stats = yappi.get_func_stats()
    stats.print_all(columns={0:("name",90), 1:("ncall", 5),
                    2:("tsub", 8), 3:("ttot", 8), 4:("tavg",8)})```

(OK after trying couple times to insert code block into the comment I gave up. this is unbelievably difficult for a programming-oriented Q&A site.)

Answer (score 6):

A new tool to handle profiling in Python is PyVmMonitor: http://www.pyvmmonitor.com/

It has some unique features such as

- Attach profiler to a running (CPython) program
- On demand profiling with Yappi integration
- Profile on a different machine
- Multiple processes support (multiprocessing, django...)
- Live sampling/CPU view (with time range selection)
- Deterministic profiling through cProfile/profile integration
- Analyze existing PStats results
- Open DOT files
- Programatic API access
- Group samples by method or line
- PyDev integration
- PyCharm integration

Note: it's commercial, but free for open source.

Answer (score 6):

Scalene is a new python profiler that covers many use cases and has a minimal performance impact:

https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene

It can profile CPU, GPU and memory utilisation at a very granular level. It also notably supports multi-threaded / parallelized python code.

Answer (score 5):

To add on to https://stackoverflow.com/a/582337/1070617,

I wrote this module that allows you to use cProfile and view its output easily. More here: https://github.com/ymichael/cprofilev

```
$ python -m cprofilev /your/python/program
# Go to http://localhost:4000 to view collected statistics.
```

Also see: http://ymichael.com/2014/03/08/profiling-python-with-cprofile.html on how to make sense of the collected statistics.

Answer (score 5):

It would depend on what you want to see out of profiling. Simple time 
metrics can be given by (bash).

```
time python python_prog.py
```

Even '/usr/bin/time' can output detailed metrics by using '--verbose' flag.

To check time metrics given by each function and to better understand how much time is spent on functions, you can use the inbuilt cProfile in python.

Going into more detailed metrics like performance, time is not the only metric. You can worry about memory, threads etc.
Profiling options:
1. **line_profiler** is another profiler used commonly to find out timing metrics line-by-line.
2. **memory_profiler** is a tool to profile memory usage.
3. **heapy (from project Guppy)** Profile how objects in the heap are used.

These are some of the common ones I tend to use. But if you want to find out more, try reading this [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028963.do)
It is a pretty good book on starting out with performance in mind. You can move onto advanced topics on using Cython and JIT(Just-in-time) compiled python.

Answer (score 3):

> Ever want to know what the hell that python script is doing? Enter the
>   Inspect Shell. Inspect Shell lets you print/alter globals and run
>   functions without interrupting the running script. Now with
>   auto-complete and command history (only on linux).
>
> Inspect Shell is not a pdb-style debugger.

https://github.com/amoffat/Inspect-Shell

You could use that (and your wristwatch).

Answer (score 3):

There's also a statistical profiler called [`statprof`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statprof/). It's a sampling profiler, so it adds minimal overhead to your code and gives line-based (not just function-based) timings. It's more suited to soft real-time applications like games, but may be have less precision than cProfile.

The [version in pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statprof/) is a bit old, so can install it with `pip` by specifying [the git repository](https://github.com/bos/statprof.py):

```
pip install git+git://github.com/bos/statprof.py@1a33eba91899afe17a8b752c6dfdec6f05dd0c01
```

You can run it like this:

```
import statprof

with statprof.profile():
    my_questionable_function()
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/10333592/320036

Answer (score 2):

I found cprofiler and other ressources to be more for optimization purpose rather than debugging.

I made my own testing module instead for simple python scripts speed testing. (In my case 1K+ lines py file was tested using ScriptProfilerPy and speedup the code by 10x in minutes afterwards.

The module ScriptProfilerPy() will run your code adding timestamp to it.
I put the module here:
https://github.com/Lucas-BLP/ScriptProfilerPy

Use:

```
from speed_testpy import ScriptProfilerPy

ScriptProfilerPy("path_to_your_script_to_test.py").Profiler()
```

output:
[image: Output of the code after testing]

Answer (score 2):

I find this function is quick and easy to use if you do not want a command line option.

To use just add @profile above each function to be profiled.

```
def profile(fnc):
    """
    Profiles any function in following class just by adding @profile above function
    """
    import cProfile, pstats, io
    def inner (*args, **kwargs):
        pr = cProfile.Profile()
        pr.enable()
        retval = fnc (*args, **kwargs)
        pr.disable()
        s = io.StringIO()
        sortby = 'cumulative'   #Ordered
        ps = pstats.Stats(pr,stream=s).strip_dirs().sort_stats(sortby)
        n=10                    #reduced the list to be monitored
        ps.print_stats(n)
        #ps.dump_stats("profile.prof")
        print(s.getvalue())
        return retval
    return inner
```

output for each function looks like this

```
   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 38 to 10 due to restriction <10>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 3151212474.py:37(get_pdf_page_count)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 fitz.py:3604(__init__)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {built-in method fitz._fitz.new_Document}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:5207(__del__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method fitz._fitz.delete_Document}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:4816(init_doc)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:5197(_reset_page_refs)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:4821(<listcomp>)
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fitz.py:4054(_getMetadata)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 weakref.py:241(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

When i'm not root on the server, I use 
[lsprofcalltree.py](https://people.gnome.org/~johan/lsprofcalltree.py) and run my program like this:

```
python lsprofcalltree.py -o callgrind.1 test.py
```

Then I can open the report with any callgrind-compatible software, like [qcachegrind](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qcachegrindwin/)

Answer (score -1):

Lots of great answers.

As a human being, my day to day measure of performance pretty much translates to "how long does it take to execute this function in seconds".... often this is influenced by many factors, like what other processes are running, machine's CPU architecture, etc.

My lazy, unscientific but relatively useful (to me) approach is to run cProfile multiple times, capture the execution time in seconds, and return the median value.

```
from io import StringIO
import cProfile
import pstats
import re
import statistics

def profile(cmd, n=100):
    def _profile(cmd):
        cProfile.run(cmd, 'statsfile')
        
        stream = StringIO()
        stats = pstats.Stats('statsfile', stream=stream)
        stats.print_stats()
        stream = stream.getvalue()    
        values = re.findall(r'[\d\.\d]+',stream.splitlines()[2])
        return float(values[-1])
    
    vals = []
    for i in range(n):
        vals.append(_profile(cmd))
        
    return statistics.median(vals)


# get the median time in seconds of 100 executions of foo()
profile.run('foo()', n=100)
```